# How to show a modal page has navigation in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to show a modal page that has navigation like Facebook android application.

How to do that?

[image: Facebook app image 1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialogFragments for this. Have two layouts for the fragment, one for all the comments, and the other one for replies to a specific comment. Initially, the first layout is shown (and the second one hidden) with all the comments like in image 1. Once they tap on replies, then hide the first layout and load the second one with appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

Make your DialogFragment a FrameLayout container :

Create two fragments and replace in it accordingly.